# WCF DataService - Cancel insert server side

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

We have build a simple Web Service using WCF Dataservices. This service is consumed by multiple applications.

Under some circumstances I would like to be able to inspect the inserted message on the server side, and cancel the insert if the inserted object meets specific conditions.

I found that i can inspect the insert with a QueryInterceptor, but did found no way to "Cancel" the insert.

Is it possible to cancel the insert server side, without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may just write a [DispatchMessageInspector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/29/creating-a-wcf-idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) and inspect the message received; and you may decide whether to execute it or not without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: That sounds like a very good option. Didn't think about using a messageinspector. Thank for the solution.